# Render result looks different than render view

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I managed to create a throne with a dragon egg on it. Now I am facing a problem:

When trying to render it, the shape of the egg, looks way different than in the render view. It seems like the texture doesn't apply. It looks quite good in the render view though.

[image: Render view vs. Rendered]
Anyone who can help me here? I am using Cycles in Blender 2.8.

Here the file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vCU6KnPzfw1ZMjgM7lQ_nmOUs5Eap2V9 (too big for blend-exchange unfortunately)

Thanks!

Comment: What render engine are you using?

Comment: Two different unrelated questions are not how this site works. Please break different unrelated questions in different posts. Keep it to one question per post. Take a moment to take the [tour] to understand how to use the site.

Comment: I understand, sorry for that. I'm using Cycles in Blender 2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your egg's subdivision surface modifier has different settings for viewport and render. Usually, the viewport setting is lower for fast visualisation and higher for best quality renderings. It looks like your settings were inverted.

[image: subdiv]

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much!